# Safari keeps closing newly opened tabs, re-opening the tabs that I just closed or navigates back when using with Tab Group

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

To illustrate the issue, think opening new tabs from Reddit's homepage for the posts that you find interesting and then Safari sometimes will just close the last tab you opened as you keep opening new tabs.

Also, it will re-open tabs. For example, you Googled something and opened 1-2 of the results then closed the Google tab and switch to one of the new tabs and suddenly the Google tab will come back.

Lastly, sometimes when you click on a link and navigate to another page in the same site, Safari will take you back. Thin clicking on someones profile on Twitter and just at the moment that the page loaded it will go back as if you clicked the back button.

All this happens only when using Tab Groups. I regularly have 3-5 tab groups with 20-50 tabs opened, I know it's not ideal but that's how I do it.

I actually filed a bug report through the Feedback assistant but so far no response. I also don't see other people complaining about it, so maybe there's a solution?

I don't use too many add-ons, I just have AdGuard enabled as an adblocker.

Any idea how to solve this unwanted behavior in Safari?

Comment: I also have this issue and AdGuard. Have you tried disabling AdGuard?

Comment: I've been having this problem ever since Tab Groups were introduced with Safari 15. I kept waiting for a point release that would fix the bugs. I can confirm that it's still just as buggy in Safari 16, a year later. The only thing keeping me on Safari at this point is my desire to use iCloud Keychain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This behavior seems to be caused by iCloud syncing problems. Specifically, the automatic sync process is interacting poorly with tab groups causing this pain.

Current workaround would be disabling iCloud syncing for Safari.

1. Go to `System Preferences`
2. Choose `Apple ID`
3. Untick `Safari`

You’ll have to re-enable sync once you are done browsing to have your changes propagate until Apple fixes this.

Comment: Not sure what is worse: not using iCloud syncing or not using tab groups.

Comment: @nohillside Tab groups, considering Apple is breaking syncing with every other update anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Good news everybody, It appears that the bug is fixed with macOS 12.5 as Apple specifically put it in the release notes!

> macOS Monterey 12.5 includes enhancements, bug fixes and security updates.
>
> - TV app adds the option to restart a live sports game already in-progress and pause, rewind, or fast-forward
> - Fixes an issue in Safari where a tab may revert back to a previous page

Edit: Unfortunately the issue is not fixed as of macOS 12.5.1, 13.0, and 14.0

Comment: Not in my experience, unfortunately

Comment: doesn't work for me either, just caught this nasty bug again after the update :( this is ridiculous. I can't trust my browser.

Comment: I assume you refer to the second item in the release note. It doesn't refer to tab groups though, also the other comments here imply that it has not been fixed.

Comment: It looks like Apple might have not fixed it after all and they are referring to another bug in the release notes. That's unfortunate.

Comment: Still not fixed on MacOS 14.0 Sonoma

Answer (score 0):

Same issue started occurring: create a new tab and moments later it closes - Mac and iPad did the same thing. The issue seemed to only occur in existing Tab Groups.

Installed latest available updates Ventura 13.3.1(a) and iPadOS 16.4.1(a), and problem persisted.

My fix (really workaround as it appears to be a bug in iCloud syncing) without logging out of iCloud was on either device:

1. Create new Tab Group to replace each problem group.
2. Move each tab from the older group to the new (MacOS right-click on tab).
3. Finally delete old Tab Groups (right-click group ‘Delete’).

A few minutes later it updated on my iPad, both I can now create a new tab without it closing seconds later.

If you have lots of tabs and tab groups, or issue in your main tab group, you may want to try logging out of iCloud and back in.

Comment: What if you are using the main tab group (named Start Page when no tabs in it; undeletable)?

Comment: Yes, you can't delete the main group, so if the issue is within the main group, recreating and deleting tab groups isn't an option. That leaves resetting the iCloud sync which only way I know to do is with one or all your devices is to log out of iCloud and then log back in.

Comment: Your answer must then be updated.