# Safari keeps reloading and moves back to previous pages

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari

On Safari MacBook Pro 2021 (macOS version 12.3), when I open a new tab and I start typing something in the address bar and then I press return, Google appears and then disappears automatically; bringing me back to the new empty tab. This sometimes happens a lot, sometimes happens occasionally, it is like random. It is annoying.

Even if it does not happen, and I am in Google page, when I click on any link on Google, Safari brings me back to the initial Google page and not to the website that I am supposed to go to after my click.

I do not know what is the problem here and how to fix it.

I cleared the history but the same issue is still present.

Comment: Are you hitting the touchbar without realising it?

Comment: I am using Macbook Pro 2021 without a touchbar. I think it is a Safari bug as I did not notice this on Chrome until now.

Comment: Happens to me quite often. Noticed it on both MacBook Pro 2022 14/16".

Comment: If you switch to a different search engine like duck duck go, does the issue persist?

Answer (score 3):

There is an ongoing problem with iCloud. I've personally reported it already and I think that everyone who experiences this problem should also.

Current workaround is to disable safari sync in iCloud. I've not had problems since, but you'll loose the sync capability.

Comment: Thx for your response but this is not an answer to the question and should be included at best as a comment as described at the [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) forum support webpage. If you don't have enough points to write a comment, pls wait until you have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

The same happens to me so I read this link

[Safari keeps closing newly opened tabs, re-opening the tabs that I just closed or navigates back when using with Tab Group](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/436025)

My best idea is this relates to the new Tab Groups feature. Rather than open a support case with apple for support, I reported it (via this form https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html).

Comment: There’s a hunch here that might even be right. Hopefully someone that has this can open a support case and provide an answer. I’m sure this is affecting some people, but no where in the question is a reproducible set of steps. Hard to tell if operator error, people don’t understand the feature or it’s a proper bug @Alper worse, if it’s a bug, it might depend on search engine / settings and what that returns.