# Safari on iOS 15.5 constantly closes all my tabs

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, tabs

Ever since upgrading from 15.4 to 15.5 iOS Safari closes all my tabs in my default tab group whenever it feels like it. Mostly in conjunction with opening a link from another app. Everything worked fine before updating.

I tap a link in e.g. Mail, Safari switches into view but fails to open the link and instead presents me one of my named tab groups, and when I switch to the default group — where all external links should be opened — all tabs are removed from the group.

Disabling Safari in iCloud [according to this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/vafq5q/safari_keeps_closing_my_tabs_on_ios_155/) won't work since it's already disabled. Is there a known solution other than switching browser?

Also, nowhere in the iOS 15.6 release notes did I find a mention of that this has been fixed. Is it still present in 15.6?

Comment: Might you [have a Mac that is in a loop and not updated to macOS 12.5?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/442810/5472) working with Apple support might be very productive as this is a bug then recently tried to address on macOS side and maybe there are unintended consequences on the iOS side still.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the link! Sounds like MacOS has similar problems. While I'm not sure exactly what a Mac in a loop means in this context I only use Mojave and Monterey. But Safari iCloud sync has been off for ages (since Apple support couldn't make it work even after going through the pain to ensure compatible OS versions both on phone and laptop...)

Comment: Perfect. Loop means safari on the Mac is not behaving in a similar manner to how it is not behaving on iOS. Sounds like you either have a crashing safari or something else… are you able to browse [safari crash logs on your device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs#Locate-Crash-Reports-and-Memory-Logs-on-the-Device) under the privacy settings in Analytics or via Xcode ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs

Comment: @bmike Thank you. Good idea — I can browse the logs but find none from Safari, although there haven't really been any outright crashes. I suppose I'll just have to consider the default tab group volatile.

Comment: I’d start with [Cirrus](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/01/21/testing-icloud-using-cirrus/) and if that doesn’t work, ulbow (same developer). Unless you know exactly what date and time the error happened or can reproduce this, you may have a needle in the haystack problem.

Comment: @bmike Interesting. Haven't seen cirrus before, but is it really applicable to Safari on iOS, and when iCloud sync is off? Sounds mostly like an iCloud tool. Anyway, I get the impression that this is a local Safari bug, since Safari also appears to use invalid indices when renaming tab groups (resulting in renaming the wrong group) which suggests a rather careless implementation of tab groups in general.

Comment: I’m having the same issue with my iPhone on iOS 16.1. My Mac is on 12.6.

Comment: @level1807 Thanks for confirming that iOS 16 does not solve the problem.